# Spring stomp websocket "Incomplete frame, resetting input buffer..."

Tags: spring-websocket, stomp

I use the spring stomp websocket as the msg-push server endpoint. When I use the web browser to connect to it , both the browser and server works well. But recently, When I use Cocos creator's app simulator to connect to my server, it always fail to connect properly. There is no error message on the server and no prompt from the client. When debugging, I found that the connection request of the simulator could only be intercepted by the handshake interceptor, but not into the ClientInboundChannelInterceptor.

After some research, I found some error logs at TRACE level as following:

```
2019-03-01 11:34:09.433  INFO [msg-push,76064c86f7a1571f,76064c86f7a1571f,true] 5300 --- [nio-9006-exec-1] c.x.m.s.i.ClientHandshakeInterceptor     : before handshake --> http://172.18.3.39:9005/stomp-ws
2019-03-01 11:34:09.456  INFO [msg-push,76064c86f7a1571f,76064c86f7a1571f,true] 5300 --- [nio-9006-exec-1] c.x.m.s.i.ClientHandshakeInterceptor     : after handshake --> websocket
2019-03-01 11:34:09.487 TRACE [msg-push,,,] 5300 --- [nio-9006-exec-1] o.s.messaging.simp.stomp.StompDecoder    : Incomplete frame, resetting input buffer...
2019-03-01 11:34:09.487 TRACE [msg-push,,,] 5300 --- [nio-9006-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.StompSubProtocolHandler        : Incomplete STOMP frame content received in session StandardWebSocketSession[id=0, uri=/stomp-ws], bufferSize=95, bufferSizeLimit=65536.
```

It seems taht there are some problem with the decoding method of the class `org.spring framework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompDecoder`. The code for the method is as follows:

```
/**
 * Decode a single STOMP frame from the given {@code buffer} into a {@link Message}.
 */
@Nullable
private Message<byte[]> decodeMessage(ByteBuffer byteBuffer, @Nullable MultiValueMap<String, String> headers) {
    Message<byte[]> decodedMessage = null;
    skipLeadingEol(byteBuffer);

    // Explicit mark/reset access via Buffer base type for compatibility
    // with covariant return type on JDK 9's ByteBuffer...
    Buffer buffer = byteBuffer;
    buffer.mark();

    String command = readCommand(byteBuffer);
    if (command.length() > 0) {
        StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = null;
        byte[] payload = null;
        if (byteBuffer.remaining() > 0) {
            StompCommand stompCommand = StompCommand.valueOf(command);
            headerAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.create(stompCommand);
            initHeaders(headerAccessor);
            readHeaders(byteBuffer, headerAccessor);
            payload = readPayload(byteBuffer, headerAccessor);
        }
        if (payload != null) {
            if (payload.length > 0) {
                StompCommand stompCommand = headerAccessor.getCommand();
                if (stompCommand != null && !stompCommand.isBodyAllowed()) {
                    throw new StompConversionException(stompCommand +
                            " shouldn't have a payload: length=" + payload.length + ", headers=" + headers);
                }
            }
            headerAccessor.updateSimpMessageHeadersFromStompHeaders();
            headerAccessor.setLeaveMutable(true);
            decodedMessage = MessageBuilder.createMessage(payload, headerAccessor.getMessageHeaders());
            if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
                logger.trace("Decoded " + headerAccessor.getDetailedLogMessage(payload));
            }
        }
        else {
            logger.trace("Incomplete frame, resetting input buffer...");
            if (headers != null && headerAccessor != null) {
                String name = NativeMessageHeaderAccessor.NATIVE_HEADERS;
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                MultiValueMap<String, String> map = (MultiValueMap<String, String>) headerAccessor.getHeader(name);
                if (map != null) {
                    headers.putAll(map);
                }
            }
            buffer.reset();
        }
    }
    else {
        StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.createForHeartbeat();
        initHeaders(headerAccessor);
        headerAccessor.setLeaveMutable(true);
        decodedMessage = MessageBuilder.createMessage(HEARTBEAT_PAYLOAD, headerAccessor.getMessageHeaders());
        if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
            logger.trace("Decoded " + headerAccessor.getDetailedLogMessage(null));
        }
    }

    return decodedMessage;
}
```

we can see if the payload == null, then the error logs occurrs：

```
logger.trace("Incomplete frame, resetting input buffer...");
```

The above situation will cause the message frame not to be processed correctly that received by the method: `org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.StompSubProtocolHandler.handleMessageFromClient()`. As the code `messages = decoder.decode(byteBuffer);` will return a empty list, so I received the log `Incomplete STOMP frame content ...`

Part of the code is as follows:

```
List<Message<byte[]>> messages;
    try {
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer;
        if (webSocketMessage instanceof TextMessage) {
            byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(((TextMessage) webSocketMessage).asBytes());
        }
        else if (webSocketMessage instanceof BinaryMessage) {
            byteBuffer = ((BinaryMessage) webSocketMessage).getPayload();
        }
        else {
            return;
        }

        BufferingStompDecoder decoder = this.decoders.get(session.getId());
        if (decoder == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No decoder for session id '" + session.getId() + "'");
        }

        messages = decoder.decode(byteBuffer);
        if (messages.isEmpty()) {
            if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
                logger.trace("Incomplete STOMP frame content received in session " +
                        session + ", bufferSize=" + decoder.getBufferSize() +
                        ", bufferSizeLimit=" + decoder.getBufferSizeLimit() + ".");
            }
            return;
        }
    }
```

I don't know why the message frame will be decoded to the null, who can help me ?

**Supplement:**

Client connection code like this:

```
var client = Stomp.client("ws://172.18.3.39:9005/msgpush/stomp-ws/");

var headers = {
    login: 'mylogin',
    passcode: 'mypasscode',
};
client.connect(headers, connectCallback);
```

**Development environment:**

springboot 2.0.3.RELEASE